# I downloaded a website to my harddrive. Is there anyway to download linked google drive files?

Tags: web

I use HTTrack and Cyotek to download the entire website to my harddrive. However links to google drive files dont work, or they have not been downloaded. Is there anyway to fix this?

Comment: can you add some context about what format you have the website in once it's downloaded? is it html files, webarchive? Have you looked into these files, looking at the google drive links? Could you post a code sample from the source code?

Comment: Once the website it downloaded I get all of the seperate files, which includes html, jpgs etc. The only thing that would not download are the pdf files which are links to google drive files.